# "starting from...ending with..."

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

> A: How computers affect our everyday life?
>
> B: In a positive way, certainly. They help with so many things,
>   ***starting from*** writing and printing your own essay and ***ending with*** developing advanced programs and digital editing...

---

> "Overall, there are seven stages in the process, ***beginning with***
>   the digging up of clay and ***culminating in*** delivery."
>   ([Source](https://www.ieltsbuddy.com/ielts-process.html))

---

Do marked phrases modify the whole main clause or just the nouns before them, "so many thing" and "seven stages" ?

For example can I rewrite them as in:

> They help with so many things, ***which start*** from writing and
>   printing your own essay and ***end with*** developing advanced
>   programs and digital editing...

---

> Overall, there are seven stages in the process, ***which begin with***
>   the digging up of clay and ***culminate in*** delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here that I think we can help with.

---

## 'Starting with' and 'Ending with' really mean 'starting' and 'ending'

### Situations with no *literal* beginning & end:

You can say

> - ✔️ **Yes:** I like all sports, from baseball to field hockey.

But this sounds awkward:

> - Awkward:   I like all sports, *starting with* swimming and *ending with* football.

It doesn't make sense to use *starting* and *ending* in this way --- these words are much more literal <sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/literal#cald4-1-1))</sup> -- use their basic definition.

It's okay to use ***"from `X` to `Y`"*** if you mean ***figuratively*** that you like many things.

So in your example:

> - ❌ *No:* They help with so many things, *starting from* writing and printing your own essay and *ending with* developing advanced programs and ...
> - ❌ *No:* They help with so many things, *which start from* writing and printing your own essay *and end with* developing advanced programs and...

The problem isn't "starting vs. start", it's that "starting" doesn't make sense here.

- Lots of people might not **start** using a computer by writing an essay.
- Lots of people might not **finish** using a computer by developing advanced programs... it makes no sense to say "finishing" with this.

Use the figurative "from `X` to `Y`" if you need to.

### Situations with a literal beginning and end

In this case, it's different; you're talking about stages, which probably means there is a first stage and a last stage:

> - **Fine**: "Overall, there are seven stages in the process, **beginning with** the digging up of clay and **culminating** in delivery."

and

> - **Fine**: "Overall, there are seven stages in the process, **which begin with** the digging up of clay and **culminate** in delivery."

These are both fine. There is nothing wrong with them. You are right to have "beginning...culminating" and "begin..culminate", using a consistent tense in each sentence.

### Finally, watch your Inversion

In this quote:

> A: How computers affect our everyday life?

This does not work as a ***stand alone question*** -- it should be

> A: **How do** computers affect our everyday life?

The only time you should see this quote as written is in an informal back-and-forth conversation.

> 1. Bob: I've always wanted to ask you a question.
> 2. Alice: About what?
> 3. Bob: About people and machines.
> 4. Alice: **How computers affect our everyday life?**
> 5. Bob: Yes, exactly.

Sentence #4 is acceptable, because it's not trying to actually ask the question -- it's trying to confirm what the question is.   ***This is a very unusual (contrived and esoteric) example***.